# JumpPath gets NoRegisteredHandler

Tags: c#, wpf

Neither Google nor searching here has helped ...

I am developing an application with Visual Studio.  I am using a new extension ("raptxt").  In XAML I set a JumpPath to a file that exists with that extension.  When I run the application the JumpPath is rejected with the error NoRegisteredHandler.

To register the extension, I went the "Open with" route, browsing for my application.  Control Panel "Default Programs" confirms that my application is the one associated with "raptxt".  File Explorer shows my program's icon by files with that extension.  As far as I can see, that means the extension is registered and associated with my application.

So why, when my application starts, are JumpPaths with that extension rejected?

Comment: I can add the exact same paths fro C# code and they go on the jump list just fine.  The only problem is adding them from XAML.  I have given up solving it, because it was only for a test; JumpPaths are dynamic enough that I have no need to add one from XAML.

Comment: FWIW: adding JumpTasks from XAML works just fine.  My only problem was adding a JumpPath from XAML.  No need to do that beyond initial testing, so I've moved on now.